# Leaflet Icon on multiple layer calling with ajax

Tags: ajax, icons, leaflet

i've a little issue for calling new icon with leaflet.

this is my code and i'm using the ajax lib leaflet-ajax.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var Icon1 = L.icon({
            iconUrl: '/img/pin.svg',
            iconSize: [38, 40] 
          });
var Icon2 = L.icon({
            iconUrl: '/img/pin2.svg',
            iconSize: [38, 40] 
          });
var Icon3 = L.icon({
            iconUrl: '/img/pin3.svg',
            iconSize: [38, 40] 
          });

function popUp(feature, layer) {layer.bindPopup('<p><b>' + feature.properties.name + '</b></p>' + '<p>' + feature.properties.description + '</p>');}
function popUp2(feature, layer) {layer.bindPopup('<p><b>' + feature.properties.name + '</b></p>' + '<p>' + feature.properties.special + '</p>');}
```

and where i think i have my issue with the call method for the icon

```
// call json 
var geojsonLayer1 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("/json/jsonlayer1.json", {onEachFeature:popUp}, {icon:Icon1});
var geojsonLayer2 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("/json/jsonlayer2.json", {onEachFeature:popUp}, {icon:Icon2});
var geojsonLayer3 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("/json/jsonlayer3.json", {onEachFeature:popUp2}, {icon:Icon3});

// create group layer
var group1 = L.layerGroup([geojsonLayer1]);
var group2 = L.layerGroup([geojsonLayer2]); 
var group3 = L.layerGroup([geojsonLayer3]);  

// call group layer on dialog box
var checkboxesJson = {
 "layer1": group1,
 "layer2": group2,
 "layer3": group3
 };
 L.control.layers(null,checkboxesJson).addTo(map);
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SO! A detailed description of what is failing and what is your expected result would help in people understanding your issue. Additionally, a very good practice is to reproduce your issue online (e.g. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/18/)), so that people can directly modify your code and provide you with a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you are trying to create a customized GeoJSON layer group through using [leaflet-ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) plugin. But you do not know how to specify the icon that should be applied on markers for points of your GeoJSON data?

It looks like this plugin will simply use all standard [L.GeoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) options that are specified in the **second argument** of the constructor / factory, as you did for your `onEachFeature` option. Note that you can have many options in one single object.

However, you should use [option `pointToLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-pointtolayer) instead of just `icon`, which is an option for a Marker. The function that you pass to `pointToLayer` should return an L.Marker, where indeed you would use the `icon` option.

For example you could do:

```js
var geojsonLayer1 = L.geoJson.ajax(
    "/json/jsonlayer1.json",
    {
        onEachFeature: popUp,
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, { icon: Icon1 })
        }
    });
```

Note that it is usually recommended to instantiate one icon per marker, even though it should work in your simple case.

By the way, note that `L.geoJson` (and with ajax plugin, `L.geoJson.ajax`) return an extended type of `L.LayerGroup`, so you do not have to import them into a new Layer Group to be able to use them in the Layers Control.

Therefore you could directly do:

```js
// call group layer on dialog box
var checkboxesJson = {
    "layer1": geojsonLayer1,
    "layer2": geojsonLayer2,
    "layer3": geojsonLayer3
};
L.control.layers(null,checkboxesJson).addTo(map);
```